# Get pearson's effect size from GAM on R

Tags: r, gam

I'm doing GAM on R. I have many variable in the model and I'd like to know the pearson's effect size for each (the aim is to compare the importance of a focal variable "A" between different data). I could use de F value but my data have different size (n) that influe the value of F...

Is it possible to find it with the result of an anova or from summary.gam ? Or is there a specific fonction that I didn't found  ?

Here my result for one of my data :

```
summary.gam(modF)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
W ~ B + s(A, k = 4) + s(C) + s(D) + s(E) + s(F) + s(G)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.39861    0.09408   4.237 2.27e-05 ***
BB2  0.42625    0.07903   5.393 6.95e-08 ***
BB3  0.37377    0.09741   3.837 0.000125 ***
BB4  0.31527    0.09500   3.319 0.000905 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
             edf    Ref.df   F    p-value    
s(A)         2.573  2.859 493.12  <2e-16 ***
s(C)         8.923  8.998 391.11  <2e-16 ***
s(D)         8.921  8.998 539.71  <2e-16 ***
s(E)         8.894  8.997 119.45  <2e-16 ***
s(F)         8.279  8.858  13.04  <2e-16 ***
s(G)         8.752  8.977  27.99  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.231   Deviance explained = 23.2%
GCV = 0.064502  Scale est. = 0.064434  n = 47402
```

Thanks !

Edit :

```
anov<-anova(modF)
anov$s.table
              edf      Ref.df      F       p-value
s(A)         2.572899 2.858737 493.11752 1.799004e-291
s(C)         8.923426 8.998212 391.10473  0.000000e+00
s(D)         8.921437 8.998192 539.70477  0.000000e+00
s(E)         8.893891 8.996777 119.44924 9.555698e-224
s(F)         8.279099 8.857940  13.03855  2.554811e-20
s(G)         8.751735 8.976584  27.99345  8.139591e-49
```